# How to Add colnames to all dataframe in a list

Tags: r

Suppose I have a list of dataframes, like this

`data = list(data.frame(arb = rep(paste(sample(LETTERS, 5), collapse = ""), 5), value = round(rnorm(5, 270, 50), 1)),  data.frame(arb = rep(paste(sample(LETTERS, 5), collapse = ""), 7), value = round(rnorm(7, 190, 70), 1)) )`

```
> data
[[1]]
    arb value
1 LIPXQ 244.5
2 LIPXQ 191.1
3 LIPXQ 237.2
4 LIPXQ 349.7
5 LIPXQ 175.3

[[2]]
    arb value
1 JVLWF 188.8
2 JVLWF 194.8
3 JVLWF 234.2
4 JVLWF 196.5
5 JVLWF 202.9
6 JVLWF 211.2
7 JVLWF 203.9
```

How do I change the column names to "Treatment" and "Doses" with lapply?
Alternatively, how do I change the name of "arb" column with a list of column names for example colname = c("1nm", "2nm")

Comment: Thanks for suggesting this. I could not find it.

Answer (score 3):

We can use `setNames`

```
data <- lapply(data, setNames, c("Treatment", "Doses"))
```

For the second case

```
data <- Map(function(x,y,z) setNames(x, c(y,z)), data, c("1nm", "2nm"), "Doses")
```

Comment: Thanks. Great solution